# How can I use the files found by one ag search as the domain for a second ag search?

Tags: ag

Suppose I do `ag -l foo`. That gets me a list of files.

How can I use ag a second time to search within just those files?

Comment: Pipe & `xargs` ? `ag -l foo | xargs ag bar`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're in the bash shell, you do this:

```
ag whatever $(ag -l foo)
```

So to find all the files that match both cat and dog:

```
ag cat $(ag -l dog)
```

You could also use `xargs`:

```
ag -l dog | xargs ag cat
```

If you used `ack`, another greplike tool, you could use the `-x` option to read the list of input files from stdin:

```
ack -l dog | ack -x cat
```

Comment: Note, that `ag -l dog | xargs ag cat` might (partially) break if `ag -l dog` returns paths that contain spaces. To address this, use `-0` on both `ag` and `xargs`, i.e. `ag -l -0 dog | xargs -0 ag cat`.